# Trying to get around performing Aggregation on a text field

Tags: javascript, velo

I am using Wix code/Javascript to try and sum items in a database collection - the only issue is whomever initially set it up created the `nos` field as text instead of an integer.

For some reason I can perform a `max` aggregation on the database which returns a 1, however I cannot sum it. (returns 0)

The way I see it is I have two options:

1. Painstakingly create a new field with the correct data type for `nos` and copy the data over and change all inputs for the field (less than keen on this idea due to it being a live database)
2. Use a function possibly `$convert:` to change the text value to an int to allow sum

My code is as below:

```
import wixData from 'wix-data';
import wixUsers from 'wix-users';

$w.onReady( function() {
   const filter = wixData.filter().eq("_owner", "SomeHashedValue");
   wixData.aggregate("CollectionName")
   .filter(filter)
   .group("_owner")
   .sum("nos", "sumnos")
   .run()
   .then( (results) => {
      console.log(results.items)
   } )
} )
```

Anyone know if option 2 is possible or if there's a better way of doing it?
Note: I know I'm not using `wix-users` in the code but I will be, it's just easier for testing not to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about Wix but in JavaScript you can easily convert a string to a number (int or float) by using the global methods:

```
var myString = "2";

var myNumber = Number(myString); // 2
var myInt = parseInt(myString); // 2
var myFloat = parseFloat(myString); // 2
```

Shorthand for converting a string to a number is to just add '+' before the string:

```
var anothernumber = +myString; // 2
```

[MDN link for Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

Comment: I ended up doing a database query and then a for loop to convert each nos within each result to an int using your 'parseInt' then totaling that. So I'm going to mark your answer as a resolution. Thanks mate!